# Updating ListBox with new list values through using a method

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to prompt a method to start upon a button click. The problem is that they are over two different classes and it is difficult to share all the relevant values over both the form and the class. I was wondering if it was possible to change a listbox's values through pressing a button on a form. At the moment mine is just staying on the first list.

My first class is the form. This is holding the physical changing of the data.

```
if (teach.Alphabet == "B")
{
    lbl1.Text = "What is the english word for White?";

    lstNum.Items.AddRange(number1);
    txtQuestion.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, english1);
}
```

It calls the method `teach.CallRandomQuestion()` to get the alphabet letter (it is a way it chooses which question to put onto the system). This is done by the following code:

```
public void CallRandomQuestion()
{      
    if (score == 1)
    {
        Alphabet = "A";
        Answer = "1";
    }

    if (score == 2)
    {
        Alphabet = "B";
        Answer = "3";
    }
}
```

Finally I have a public int `score` which starts at 1 and adds one every time the correct answer is given. So if the correct answer is given, the second question `B` should show in the listbox, but doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Showinlistbox()
    {      
        // Add a  listBox named  listBox1 

        // Add Score
        score++;
        CallRandomQuestion();    
        //if you want mutual-exclusion lock add lock (listBox1) 
        listBox1.Items.Add(Alphabet);
     }
```